# Are we loosing data when we use .next() or .take() on tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory object?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I create a data generator like this:

```
# Create test_dataset
test_dataset = \
  tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(directory=test_dir,
                                                      labels='inferred', 
                                                      label_mode='int', 
                                                      class_names=None,
                                                      seed=42, 
                                                      )
# Explore the first batch
for images, labels in test_dataset.take(1):
  print(labels)
```

it returns:

```
tf.Tensor([5 3 8 3 8 5 7 6 3 8 4 2 4 5 5 4 0 1 0 5 5 2 6 0 7 9 9 0 4 9 6 4], shape=(32,), dtype=int32)
```

if I re-run the last part as below:

```
for images, labels in test_dataset.take(1):
  print(labels)
```

it returns something different from the first time:

```
tf.Tensor([0 6 2 5 5 7 5 2 7 4 0 5 0 4 6 5 8 7 7 3 5 1 1 9 5 2 6 6 6 6 2 0], shape=(32,), dtype=int32)
```

if I recreate `test_dataset` and explore it as below:

```
# Create test_dataset
test_dataset = \
  tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(directory=test_dir,
                                                      labels='inferred', 
                                                      label_mode='int', 
                                                      class_names=None,
                                                      seed=42, 
                                                      )
# Explore the first batch
for images, labels in test_dataset.take(1):
  print(labels)
```

it returns the same as the first time:

```
tf.Tensor([5 3 8 3 8 5 7 6 3 8 4 2 4 5 5 4 0 1 0 5 5 2 6 0 7 9 9 0 4 9 6 4], shape=(32,), dtype=int32)
```

Well, I conclude that when I use the `take` method, the batch is popped out and lost and no more accessible to be used in  the modeling and validation, etc.

My question is:

- Am I right? Is the first batch lost if I run `test_dataset.take(1)`
- If the answer to the above question is yes, is there any way not to loose a bacth when trying to explore batches in `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not about losing the batch. Function `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` has an argument `shuffle` that is default value is `True`. That said, dataset is shuffled at each iteration.

If we dive into the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py#L211):

```
  if shuffle:
    # Shuffle locally at each iteration
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=batch_size * 8, seed=seed)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

Under the hood as you can see it creates a `tf.data` object which has [shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) method. [Shuffle Method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) has an argument `reshuffle_each_iteration = True` by default. With 2nd take method you are iterating over the dataset again that causes it to get shuffled again.

If you set `shuffle = False` for the dataset, then the data will be sorted in a alphanumeric order and its order won't change at each iteration.

Comment: I do not think this is true. Because I have used `seed=42` and note that when I do it again, I see the same as the first first result.
`tf.Tensor([5 3 8 3 8 5 7 6 3 8 4 2 4 5 5 4 0 1 0 5 5 2 6 0 7 9 9 0 4 9 6 4], shape=(32,), dtype=int32)`

Comment: When you provide the seed they are shuffled in same *randomness*.

Comment: yes when I set `shuffle=False` I get the same each time but I am still confused. They are shuffled in the same randomness and saved in `test_dataset` each time. I am now using the `take` method on something that is shuffled. When I use the `take` method again, I am taking from the same and not shuffling it. I am taking the first from a shuffled set but the same each time.

Comment: Under the hood as you can see it creates a tf.data object which has `shuffle` method. [Shuffle Method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) has an argument `reshuffle_each_iteration = True` by default. With 2nd take method you are iterating over the dataset again that causes it to get shuffled again.

Comment: I think your last comment is the answer to the question. I would edit the answer and include it in the answer so that others can easily find it. Thank you

Comment: Why did you remove the accepted mark from the answer?

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at `tf.data` API. Also I don't see a reason to keep it open since my answer explains it. I may edit it if you say why you are confused still.